# C# Grouping by calculated values isn't working

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Why isn't this grouping correctly? I'm grouping by day of week and day of month, and I end up with four results, not three.

```
query.GroupBy(datapoint =>
{
    var timeDimensionValue = (DateTime)datapoint.Dimensions[TimeDimension];
    var keyValues = groupingFunctions.Select(func => func(timeDimensionValue));

    return keyValues.ToArray(); // Ex: { "Monday", 15 };
});
```

Data:

`DateTime(2023, 7, 17, 15, 0, 0)`

`DateTime(2023, 7, 19, 7, 0, 0)` // same

`DateTime(2023, 7, 19, 7, 0, 0)` // same

`DateTime(2023, 7, 21, 11, 30, 0)`

Comment: I don't believe grouping by arrays work the way you want it to. The objects needs to be comparable, and arrays aren't.

Comment: Arrays are reference types that compare by reference, not value.

Comment: rather than grouping by the array, create a string that represents your data `return keyValues.Aggregate((a,b) => $"{a},{b}");`

Comment: It seems like your array is `{ Day of Week, Hour of Day }`. If that's the case an anonymous type or a tuple would work fine.

Comment: @Nifim The string option did work, thank you for the suggestion, but it made typed keys inaccessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping by an array is not what you want, because arrays don't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. You want to group by the values the array contains. Since you said in a comment that this array is actually a `IList<object>` and dynamic, so can contain anything, you need a custom comparer which can handle that:

```
public class ObjectListComparer: IEqualityComparer<IList<object>>
{
    public bool Equals(IList<object> x, IList<object> y)
    {
        if(x == null && y == null) return true;
        if(x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IList<object> obj)
    {
        return string.Join(",", obj?.Select(obj => obj) ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>()).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you could use this comparer in `GroupBy` and many other LINQ methods:

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(x => {
    var timeDimensionValue = (DateTime)datapoint.Dimensions[TimeDimension];
    List<object> keyValues = groupingFunctions.Select(func => func(timeDimensionValue));
    return keyValues;
}, new ObjectListComparer());
```

Since it's a comparer for `IList<object>` you can use it for your `List<object>` but also for `object[]`.

Comment: The whole thing is dynamic. I don't know what the fields or groupings are until runtime.

Comment: @SteveAndrews: So `keyValues` is an `object[]`?

Comment: `List<object>`, yes.

Comment: @SteveAndrews: have a look at my edited answer then.

Comment: That works great, and now I understand comparison better. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot group by arrays like that, as they have no equality semantics based on their contents, only on array reference.

**You can use a `HashSet`** instead, along with a `HashSetComparer`

```cs
query.GroupBy(datapoint =>
{
    var timeDimensionValue = (DateTime)datapoint.Dimensions[TimeDimension];
    var keyValues = groupingFunctions.Select(func => func(timeDimensionValue));

    return keyValues.ToHashSet(); // Ex: { "Monday", 15 };
}, HashSet<object>.CreateSetComparer());
```

You may wish to find a way to store the actual hashcode for each set, for performance reasons.